# How to Make MemStore in Golang for Incoming Websocket Data

Tags: go, websocket, real-time-data

I am fetching 100 symbols from a trading platform api by consuming their websocket.
Data is received in **[]map[string]interface{}** with every websocket onMessage.

```
    //websocket on message function
    onMessage(message []map[string]interface{}){
        lock.Lock();
        defer lock.Unlock();
        storedata(message []map[string]interface{})
    }
```

but the data is not consistent means every 100 symbols are not there on every onMessage
so to make store consistent I have made a variable my own **var livestore []map[string]interface{}** to store live data.

```
    var livestore []map[string]interface{}
```

```
func storedata(livedata []map[string]interface{}){
       for _,m:= range livedata{
             for_,l := range livestore{
              if(m["ts"]==l["ts"]{
              m["name"]==l["name"]
              m["price"]==l["price"]
              m["open"]==l["open"]
              .......

              }
             }
       }
}
```

To stop concurrent readwrite we used var lock sync.RWmutex

Now while reading

```
  func getsymdata(name string) map[string]interface{}{
             lock.Rlock();
             defer lock.RUnlock();
             d:= make[map[string]interface{}
              for_,l := range livestore{
              if(l["name"]==name {
              d["name"]==l["name"]
              d["price"]==l["price"]
              d["open"]==l["open"]
              .......

              }

                 return d
             }
  }
```

now problem is that i think websocket data recieving is so fast that write lock is never be unlocked.. so the function get data is not recieving...

i tried with channels without buffer
issue same .. write lock or read lock..

we are reading every second 100 symbols with **getsymdata** function

```
    sym1price  = getsymdata("sym1name")["price"]
    sym2price  = getsymdata("sym2name")["price"]
    sym3price  = getsymdata("sym3name")["price"]
```

Issue : not recieving new data on getsymdata...